# javascript regexp validation to match specific pattern to accept from textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have one form with textbox and user needs to insert width X height format value so I need to validate whether it is in correct format or not using JavaScript regexp validations.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="txt" class="txt_val" value=""/>
<input type="submit" class="clk" value="submit"/>

<script>
  $(".clk").click(function(){
    var number=$(".txt_val").val();
    var compare=/[0-9]{2}^[a-z .x-]{1}[0-9]{2}/;
    if(number.match(compare)){
      alert('match');
    }
    else{
      alert('not match');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Expected output with cases:

1) format should be like this

```
10X10  or 23X24  or 36X24 or 44X56
```

like any width by height with uppercase or lowercase 'x'

2) any number with two digits following widthXheight and charecter 'x' can be upper case or lower case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be `/[0-9]{2}[x|X][0-9]{2}$/`

**Where:**

`[0-9]` - Matches number in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57)

`{2}` - Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

`[x|X]` - Match the character x or X

`$` - Asserts position at the end of a line

```js
$(".clk").click(function(){
  var number=$(".txt_val").val();
  var compare=/[0-9]{2}[x|X][0-9]{2}$/;
  if(number.match(compare)){
    alert('match');
  }
  else{
    alert('not match');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txt" class="txt_val" value=""/>
<input type="button" class="clk" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: worked for me in perfect way

Comment: @MASamad, you are most welcome:)

Comment: can we validate for decimal values

Comment: I want to  accept/allow  below values :                                                                   23.15 X 24.16   or  22.1 X24.1   or 22.1X 24.12   can you please mention the way to accept above cases.

Comment: @MASamad, try `/(\d*\.)?\d+(\ )?[x|X](\ )?(\d*\.)?\d+$/`

Comment: but 12X13 should accept and 122X13 not accept  i kept {1,2} but it is not working

Comment: need your little help here with accept following cases

Comment: This values should  accept  12X13  ,12.13X14.15 , 12X14.15 , 12X14.1 ,12 X14.22  ,12.1X14 ,12.1 X14.12 ,12.11 x14 thses are the format sizes will vary in any two didgit

Comment: could you suggest me about this

Comment: @MASamad, your input data does clarify all the condition, better you should first node down all the condition to meet. Anyway, for the above input to pass trough you can try `/^(\d*\.)?[0-9]{1,2}(\ )?[x|X](\ )?(\d*\.)?[0-9]{1,2}$/`

Comment: thanks a lot, whatever requirement I have mentioned as it  is working perfectly with your updated answer, greate work.